# How to convert my Backbone model to XML?

Tags: xml, backbone.js, model

I want to produce an XML for every Backbone model that I create. I know that through Backbone.sync we can convert the models to xml and save them to the server. But I am only using local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normal JSON to xml conversion, backbone has no much benefit in your case
you can check this library 
https://github.com/alanclarke/node-json2xml

it converts json object to xml, you can just call it passing model.attributes

Comment: What I did is to read the XML schema using JQuery and then replace the values with the models' attributes. I guess using the library you suggested may be easier though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here..http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/convert-json-xml and here http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3540648.htm (got the code from this site)

```
   function OBJtoXML(obj, d) {
d = (d) ? d : 0;
var rString = "\n";
var pad = "";
for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    pad += " ";
}
if (typeof obj === "object") {
    if (obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") !== -1) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            rString += pad + "<item>" + obj[i] + "</item>\n";
        }
        rString = rString.substr(0, rString.length - 1)
    }
    else {
        for (i in obj) {
            var val = OBJtoXML(obj[i], d + 1);
            if (!val)
                return false;
            rString += ((rString === "\n") ? "" : "\n") + pad + "<" + i + ">" + val + ((typeof obj[i] === "object") ? "\n" + pad : "") + "</" + i + ">";
        }
    }
}
else if (typeof obj === "string") {
    rString = obj;
}
else if (obj.toString) {
    rString = obj.toString();
}
else {
    return false;
}
return rString;
}
   function JSONtoXML(json) {
    return eval("OBJtoXML(" + json + ");");
   }
```